# unable to setup gunicorn daemon process

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2

I am unable to set up the gunicorn daemon process in an ec2 instance. Below are sample code and error/log messages.

**myproject-backend/gunicorn.conf**

```
import os
import multiprocessing

from dotenv import load_dotenv

# load .env file
APP_ROOT = os.path.dirname(__file__)
dotenv_path = os.path.join(APP_ROOT, '.env')
load_dotenv(dotenv_path=dotenv_path)

# Please refer http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/latest/settings.html# for ducumentation.
bind = os.getenv('GUNICORN_BIND')
workers = multiprocessing.cpu_count() * 2 + 1
daemon = True
preload = True
reload = False
umask = os.getenv('GUNICORN_UMASK')
group = os.getenv('GUNICORN_GROUP')
user  = os.getenv('GUNICORN_USER')
pythonpath = os.getenv('PYPATH')
```

**myproject-backend/.env**

```
# This will load environment specific dynamic configurations.
# possible value - "development", "testing", "stage", "production"
INSTANCE_TYPE="production"

# gunicorn config
GUNICORN_UMASK=0
GUNICORN_GROUP='ubuntu'
GUNICORN_USER='ubuntu'
GUNICORN_BIND='localhost:8080'
#GUNICORN_BIND='127.0.0.1:8080'
PYPATH='/home/ubuntu/project/myproject-backend/'
```

**/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.service**

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
After=network.target

[Service]
User=ubuntu
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/ubuntu/project/myproject-backend
ExecStart=/home/ubuntu/project/myproject-backend/.venv/bin/gunicorn -c /home/ubuntu/project/myproject-backend/gunicorn.conf wsgi:app
#ExecStart=/home/ubuntu/project/myproject-backend/.venv/bin/gunicorn --access-logfile - --workers 3 --bind unix::8080 wsgi:app

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

**sudo systemctl  status gunicorn**  returns

```
gunicorn.service - gunicorn daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead) since Tue 2019-08-27 01:12:22 UTC; 50s ago
 Main PID: 4515 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Aug 27 01:12:21 ip-172-31-40-176 systemd[1]: Started gunicorn daemon.
```

.
**sudo journalctl -u gunicorn**

> Aug 27 00:47:15 ip-172-31-40-176 systemd[1]: Started gunicorn daemon.
>   Aug 27 00:58:09 ip-172-31-40-176 systemd[1]: Started gunicorn daemon.

If you use commented `ExecStart` line in `/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.service` then everything looks good, but I want to run `gunicorn` from the config file. How to do this?

Answer (score 0):

In `gunicorn.cfg` file when I change

```
umask = os.getenv('GUNICORN_UMASK')
group = os.getenv('GUNICORN_GROUP')
user  = os.getenv('GUNICORN_USER')
```

to

```
umask = 0
user = None
group = None
```

Then everything looks good. I don't know why and how. but yes it fixed the problem. If someone here can explain to me then it will be great.